# Pause the movement of an SKPhysicsBody?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

In my SpriteKit game several Sprites are moved by an impulse:

```
[sprite.physicsBody applyImpulse:vector]
```

Is it possible to stop the Sprites movement and then continue it on the designated route?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
   `mySpriteNode.paused = YES;`